# ¿Como encontrar los archivos de mi XAMPP en Mac?

Tags: xampp, macos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En la imagen, muestro que tengo la ruta:

```
nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm
```

Y quiero accesar desde la Terminal y nada, no me deja y ya llevo rato acá con esto, sabrán como llegar a mis archivos?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tenes que montar el volumen. En el panel de XAMPP hay un botón o tab de Volume y ahí esta el comando para hacer el mount del volumen.

Después en una terminal, si corres el comando `mount`, te va a mostrar el volumen y donde esá montado en tu mac.

En mi caso, la instalación default lo está montando en:

```
<mi home>/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/
```

Por otro lado si querés abrir una Terminal en la máquina virtual, también desde el panel de XAMPP, en el botón o tab General, tenés la oopción 'Open Terminal'.